# Laravel - calling a controller method (using custom form-request validation) from another method within the same controller

Tags: laravel, validation

How do I call "create" method from within the "store" method and pass it a custom request with data ?

```
public function create(createUserRegForm $request) {
    $validated = $request->validated();
    return view('pages.user-form', ['user_id' => $validated['user_id']);
}

public function store(Request $request) {
    // -- code --
    $new_request = new createUserRegForm(['user_id' => $response]);
    $this->create($new_request);
}
```

**Trying the above code gives me an error :**

Comment: What's inside `$response` in your `store()` method?

Comment: a string containing user id.